# mysql update if exist else insert

Tags: php, mysql

In my form, I have file type input field that is dynamically generated by add more click button.
Everything is ok, when I insert the data but i'm facing problem when I update second table which 
I used for only store file type data.

I have analysed some case:

```
Case 1: if value exist is equal to new value then update
Case 2: if value not exist then insert data
Case 3: if value exist and greater than previous value then update the previous value and insert new data
case 4: if value exist and less than previous value then update previous and other value will be remain same(no change).
```

I have tried so far 
`$array_filename = trim($array_filename, ","); 
$filename_array = explode(',', $array_filename); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`tbl_name_2`WHERE`job_app_id`='$editId' "); 
$res = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
for($i=0;$i<coun($filename_array);$i++) { 
 $insertQuery = "REPLACE INTO`tbl_name_2`(`id`,`job_app_id`,`file_name`) VALUES ('$res[$i]','$editId','$filename_array[$i]')"; 
 $isInsert = mysql_query($insertQuery) or die(mysql_error()); 
}`

---

Comment: post some of your code/queries. and tell us where you having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

> mysql update if exist else insert

Should better be described as *INSERT ELSE UPDATE* - and that's what you can to with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` keywords and the proper unique key constraints (assuming `uniqueKey` column to be unique):

```
INSERT INTO 
   myTable (`id`, `uniqueKey`, `value2`) VALUES (null,"test1",17) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
   value2 = 17;
```

This covers your case `1` and `2`: Data is inserted or updated.

For your case `3` and `4` it is unclear, what you are asking? It seems like these statements are targeting multiple tables, or what do you mean by *update the previous value and insert new data*?

Comment: Thanks for help. Suppose, I have inserted one image in second table after that i update that and now I have two image for updating. In this case, i will update previous data from second table and insert also because there are two image

Comment: Case 1 & Case 2 easy task but I'm having trouble with Case3 & case4. Data update into multiple table